# How can I expand the /dev/root partition?

Tags: linux, root, dev

How can I expand /dev/root? I can't seem to do this using an LVExtend command.

Thanks,

James

Comment: Please be more verbose. What happens when you try to use lvextend? What is the exact command you are trying to use? Is there still space available in your logical volume so you can extend it without adding new physical volumes to your volume group? And so on. We might be gurus and all, but psychic skills are not available here.

Comment: @Janne, Here's the command I was using; 'lvextend -L+3G /vg00'

Comment: Forget the `/`.

Comment: Still doesn't work :(

Comment: root@s15430558 [~]# lvextend -L+3G vg00
  Path required for Logical Volume "vg00"
  Please provide a volume group name
  Run `lvextend --help' for more information.

Comment: Oh, my bad, lvextend needs full path to logical volume. :-) Some something like /dev/mapper/yourvg-lvol0 or whatever the path is.

Comment: @Janne: It'll also just take a `vg/lv` pair, as I provided in my answer.  @James: Put this sort of additional information in your question, rather than dumping it in a comment where it's unreadable.  The output of `lvs` would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your root partition on LVM, you can use `lvextend -L+<size>G <vg>/<lv>` followed by `resize2fs /dev/<vg>/<lv>` (assuming an `ext[234?]` root filesystem; the appropriate alternative command should be used if you're running a different filesystem).

On the other hand, you may not be using LVM for your root filesystem, in which case... who knows what you need to do?  Certainly not us.

Comment: What would I put in the place of '<lv>'? Thanks!

Comment: The name of your root LV...

Comment: Where could I find that, please? :)

Comment: Look: 

PV Name               /dev/xvda3
  VG Name               vg00
  PV Size               273.80 GB / not usable 783.00 KB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size (KByte)       4096
  Total PE              70092
  Free PE               40652
  Allocated PE          29440
  PV UUID               zWbdU2-X0vX-E2oq-hNby-9LHP-47wy-4fvb0v